# How to increase Rate Limit at runtime?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-web-api, backend, rate-limiting, .net-7.0

I've read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/rate-limit?view=aspnetcore-7.0#additional-resources) but couldn't see if it is possible.

For example, how to implement a token bucket limiter that is increased limit if user pays for it? There is `autoReplenish` property but what happens if you set it to `false`? Can we increase the limit at runtime? Is there an injectable service for it?

Has anyone experienced it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, how to implement a token bucket limiter that is increased limit if user pays for it?

The doc shows something very similar to what you have requested - you can return different partition keys and limiters for paid and unpaid users:

```cs
builder.Services.AddRateLimiter(opts => opts
    .AddPolicy(policyName: "somePolicyName", partitioner: httpContext =>
    {
        var userName = httpContext.User.Identity?.Name ?? string.Empty;

        // determine somehow if user is paid, for example set corresponding claim for token
        // or any other method:
        var isPaid = httpContext.User.HasClaim("paid", "true");
        if (isPaid)
        {
            return RateLimitPartition.GetTokenBucketLimiter("Paid!:" + userName, _ =>
                new TokenBucketRateLimiterOptions 
                {
                    // values for paid users
                });
        }

        return RateLimitPartition.GetTokenBucketLimiter("Unpaid!:" + userName, _ =>
            new TokenBucketRateLimiterOptions
            {
                // values for free users
            });
    }));
```